# Python Django: Filter within for loops

Tags: python, django, for-loop, filter

**Context**

I currently have `Building` and `Room` objects stored in my database - linked by a *ForeignKey*.

I'm trying to generate a `Room` query set for each `Building` using loops and `objects.filter()`

**Problem**

See the code posted below - I can't seem to solve a seemingly simple problem.

`BuildingList` returns two objects, but for some reason, my for loop only queries and appends a `RoomList` for one of two buildings. (The second one)

I don't understand why, but *`RoomList = Room_Data.objects.filter(Room_Building=b)`* seems to disrupt the logic and flow of my basic for loop.

**Python Script:**

```py
#
#
# 1.) GET DATA FOR RELEVANT SET OF BUILDINGS

FusionBuildingName = "Renal Dialysis Unit x6"

BuildingRoomLists = []



# GET DATA FOR ALL BUILDINGS MATCHING 'FusionBuildingName'
BuildingList = Building_Data.objects.filter(Building_Name=FusionBuildingName)

print(len(BuildingList))
print(BuildingList)


# GENERATE BUILDING ROOM LISTS
for b in BuildingList:
    
    print(b)
    print("Building Author: " + b.Building_Author)
    
    print("Building Room List:")
    
    # GET LIST OF ROOM OBJECTS FOR CURRENT BUILDING
    RoomList = Room_Data.objects.filter(Room_Building=b)
    
    print(str(RoomList))
    
    # APPEND LIST OF ROOM OBJECTS TO BUILDING ROOM LIST
    BuildingRoomLists.append(RoomList)
```

**Below is what my Python Shell returns upon running the above code:**

```
In [43]:
In [44]:     ...:     ...:     ...:     ...:     ...:     ...:     ...: Building_Data object (1)
1
Building Author : Angel Mahchut
Building_Data object (2)
2
Building Author : AusHFG

In [45]: Building Room List:

In [46]:
In [46]:
In [46]:
In [47]:
In [48]:
In [48]:
In [48]: <QuerySet [<Room_Data: Room_Data object (41)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (42)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (43)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (44)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (45)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (46)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (47)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (48)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (49)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (50)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (51)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (52)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (53)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (54)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (55)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (56)>, <Room_Data: Room_Data object (57)>]>

In [49]:
In [49]:
In [50]:
```

Despite looping through 2 building objects, `Building Room List:` and `<QuerySet [<Room_Data:...` are only printed once - and for some reason the ordering of print outputs is incorrect?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this issue for a while now...

Comment: is `Room_Data.Room_Building` a foreign key field to `Building_Data` ? what is the relation between the 2 model classes ?

Comment: Yes, I've set it up as a one (building) to many (room) relationship with the following line in the `Room_Data` model class: `Room_Building = models.ForeignKey(Building_Data, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: Your question doesn't specify how or what you require, maybe it should be rechecked, you might have already solved it.

Answer (score 1):

you are appending a whole `queryset` in to the array, so you will find a `queryset` as a single element of your array. If you are trying to make a list of objects of the queryset... you can simply make it an array using `list()`.

eg:

```
BuildingRoomLists = []
FusionBuildingName = "Renal Dialysis Unit x6"

BuildingList = Building_Data.objects.filter(Building_Name=FusionBuildingName)

for b in BuildingList:
    RoomList = Room_Data.objects.filter(Room_Building=b)
    RoomList = list(RoomList)
    BuildingRoomLists += RoomList)
```

This will do...

Comment: Thanks for the response - although something is still wrong with my loop. There are two buildings, so 'for b in BuildingList' should Generate a 'RoomList' for both of them. For some reason the loop will only generate a queryset for the second of two buildings. My final array should be along the lines of : [ [ Room 1.1, Room 1.2... x40 Rooms ], [ Room 2.1, Room 2.2... x 17 Rooms] ]. Instead it is only: [ [ Room 2.1, Room 2.2... x 17 Rooms ] ]. I can't figure out why the first buildings Room queryset is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

The relation between the 2 models  `Building_Data` and `Room_Data` is not clear since you didn't mention that in your question, but if `Room_Data.Room_Building` is foreign key to `Building_Data` and you simply want to retrieve all rooms of the buildings which satisfy certain condition (in your case, `Building_Name=FusionBuildingName`) , you can simply use [fieldname__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup in `filter()`, instead of looping through each `Building_Data` instance.

[update] fix typo in code

quick example:

```py
# retrieve list of buildings instances (represented as QuerySet) with specific naming pattern ....
BuildingList = Building_Data.objects.filter(Building_Name=FusionBuildingName)
# find out all rooms associated with the given list of buildings,
RoomList = Room_Data.objects.filter(Room_Building__in=BuildingList)
# convert (from QuerySet) to list, start database access
BuildingRoomLists = list(RoomList)
```

The example above could reduce your code implementation also number of database accesses, because [queryset is lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

Comment: Thanks, this can lead to a potential workaround. All I will need to do now is split the Room list into separate lists for each building. I was hoping to solve the original problem with my loop - I've encountered this same problem numerous times throughout my code, but this will do for the time being :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue with a minor update to the following line of code:

```py
RoomList = Room_Data.objects.filter(Room_Building=b)
```

To

```py
RoomList = Room_Data.objects.filter(Room_Building=BuildingList[BuildingList.index(b)])
```

Now I can successfully generate independent querysets of `Room_Data` objects for each `Building_Data` without the loop failing - though I'm not entirely sure why this change was necessary.